# Как получить день недели в JS

Tags: javascript

Передаю в текстовое поле дату с помощью js, но дата передается в виде 4.12.2018, а нужно 04.12.2018, подскажите как подправить, делаю так:

```
 var dsec = new Date();
 var mm = dsec.getMonth() + 1;
 $('#inputDateSecond').val(dsec.getDate() + "." +
            mm + "." +
            dsec.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dsec = new Date();
var mm = dsec.getMonth() + 1;
var dt = dsec.getDate();
if (dt < 10) dt = '0' + dt;
$('#inputDateSecond').val(dt + "." + mm + "." + dsec.getFullYear());
```

Comment: ругается `Invalid left hand side for assignment
            if (dsec.getDate() < 10) d`

Comment: у меня все работает https://jsfiddle.net/5r6wntsL/

Comment: Если делаю так `var dsec = new Date();
            var mm = dsec.getMonth() + 1;
            if (dsec <= 10) dsec = '0' + dsec;
            $('#inputDateSecond').val(dsec + "." +
                    mm + "." +
                    dsec.getFullYear());` то дата такого вида Tue Dec 04 2018 10:02:37

Comment: перейдите по ссылке в jsfiddle (впрочем я поменял код в своем ответе), что я дал выше. там ровно ваш случай и в input дата нормально вставляется в формате 04.12.2018. Кроме того, не делайте сравнение <=, иначе у вас 10ое число будет выводится как '010'

Comment: то я просто одну строку закоментил, а там где <= я хотел 9 поставить) спасибо большое!!!